# A random variable has density function $fT(t)=λ^2 t e^{-λ t}$, where $λ = .05$. What is the expected lifetime of this light bulb?

Tags: probability-theory

The lifetime, measure in hours, of the ACME super light bulb is a random
variable $T$ with density function 
$$
fT(t)=\lambda^2 t e^{-.05t},$$ 
where $\lambda = .05$. What is the
expected lifetime of this light bulb?

For this, I tried to find the integral of the density function by doing an integration by parts by setting $U=-.05t$, and $dv=e^{-.05t} dt$ to get $(.05)te^{-.05t}+\frac{e^{-.05t}}{0.05}$, then I applied the expected value definition formula to eventually get positive infinity in the end. However, $E(x)=40$? How are they finding this expected value?

Answer (score 1):

${\int\limits_{t=0}^\infty t\ \lambda^2\ t\ e^{-0.05 t}\ dt \over \int\limits_{t=0}^\infty \lambda^2\ t\ e^{-0.05 t}\ dt } = 40$

Answer (score 1):

The density is a specific case of the gamma distribution. In general, a random variable $X\sim\text{Gamma}(\alpha, \lambda)$ has density
$$
f(x)=\frac{\lambda^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-\lambda x}
$$
for $x\in(0,\infty)$ and $0$ otherwise so that $E(X)=\alpha/\lambda$ (obtained by integration by parts). In your case, the density corresponds to a $\text{Gamma}(2,0.05)$ so that the expected value is 
$$
\frac{2}{0.05}=40.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$f \sim gamma(2,2)$

$tf_{T}(t) = \lambda^2 t^2e^{t/2} = \frac{2}{\lambda} \frac{\lambda^3t^2e^{t/2}}{\Gamma(3)} = \frac{2}{\lambda} g_{T}(t)$

where

$g \sim gamma(3,2)$

And use the fact that the integration of pdf over complete sample space is $1$.